# Is there a way to customize application properties for a third party spring boot application without source code

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a requirement where we use third party spring boot application jar that can be used as a stand alone application.  In the application properties file, it allows specifying user name and password.  I need to inject secret like this programmatically without source code for the third party spring boot application.  Is there a way to do this?  Thanks.

I tried using the jar as a dependency but since it is an executable jar, it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any serious application will hard code an user name and a password in their `application.properties` configuration file without providing a way to provide your own. And they should clearly document how to do this.

What you can do is to unzip their jar and have a look at `application.properties` file and hopefully they control these values via some environment variables. If this is the case then your problem is solved. If not I am afraid you will have to stick your nose in their decompiled code and try to understand how they load those vales. Those ones from `application.properties` might be just some default values and support a different way of injecting the runtime ones such as bringing them from a config server a secrets vault, etc

Ultimately you should come in touch with the third party provider and ask for support.

Hope some of the above ideas will help.